# Movable dashboard-like panels for web

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder, is there any *free* complete solution for implementing web dashboard like [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/portal/portal.html)? All I need is to implement such movable widget panels but any additional functional will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI? GWT? Dojo? Anything with widgets can implement this.

Comment: Can you give some links with examples?

Comment: [YUI](http://skypoet.net/yui/examples/iGoogle/iGoogle1.html), [jQuery](http://drupal.geek.nz/static/dashboard/demo.html), [Dojo](http://www.skynet.ie/~sos/misc/dojo/dojox/widget/tests/test_PortletInGridContainer.html?theme=soria), etc.